# Click event on Page_Prerender in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my application there is a grid which gets loaded once the user click on row which has some data, but now my requirement is like I want to load the grid at the time when page gets loaded, so for that I just want to call the Click event to happen automatically at the Page_Prerender itself. 
Can anyone please help me out with the solution.

Comment: You need to do it in the Page_Load event not in the Page_Prerender event.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add a little bit of code explaining your desired behavior and the current behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a grid view like this.

`<GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" />`

You can easily data bind it in Page_PreRender event with

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs args)
{
    gvChildGrid.DataSource = yourdatasource;
    gvChildGrid.DataBind();
}
```